# Android app, How to support 64-bit architectures?

Tags: android, architecture, 64-bit, lib

Last time when I was releasing a new version of my app on Play Store, It showed this warning : **This release is complaint with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.**

According to the Android Developer website : [Support 64-bit architectures](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#assess-your-app)

> **Look for native libraries using APK Analyzer**
>
> 1. Open Android Studio, and open any project.
> 2. From the menu, select Build > Analyze APK…
> 3. launch APK analyzer
> 4. Choose the APK you wish to evaluate.
> 5. Look within the lib folder, which is where you will find any '.so' files. If you can not find any '.so' files in your app at all, then your app is already ready and no further action is required. If you see armeabi-v7a or x86, then you have 32-bit libraries.

All the code of the app is written in Java, But I am using some libraries.

The problem is that I don't see the lib folder, After following the above steps.
[image: The folders that I see]

Comment: Your question is unclear. The message says that your app is compliant with the requirements, so what is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Jörg I said : **The problem is that I don't see the lib folder, After following the above steps.**, I have to look for native libraries, As the it is written in the doc. : for each native 32-bit architecture you support you must include the corresponding 64-bit architecture.

Comment: Well, are you using any native libs?

Comment: I still don't understand what your problem is. The message from the Play Store tells you that your app is compliant with the requirements. You are trying to find libraries that are not compliant. You can't find any. Why are you surprised that you can't find any non-compliant libraries if Google tells you that you are fully compliant?

Comment: I am sorry, I read the warning wrongly, I read it **Complaint** not **Compliant**, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one (or more) of your libraries include a native binaries, but they don't support the 64-bit architecture.
You can check this by taking your apk file, and unzipping it (you can rename to `.zip` and then unzip for example).

In the zip, open the `lib` directory, and check it's contents. The 64-bit versions should be in the `arm64-v8a` and in the `x86_64` directories. As far as I know, Android only looks for the ARM one, and displays a warning if that one is missing. You can usually find out which dependency includes those files, from the native file names inside the other directories in `lib`.
Usually updating that library to its latest version should be enough, otherwise you might have to look into alternatives.